# Why are the "Battery| Battery" and "Battery | Power" settings disabled in System Preferences?

Tags: macos, battery

I have a 2015 MBPro running *Big Sur* 11.5.1 . Why would  the settings from the question title be disabled?  My account is an administrator on the machine.

[image]

[image]

This is a personal laptop - no VPN, MDM, corporate policies, or anything work related.

Comment: Does this machine participate in an MDM?

Comment: Is this your personal laptop or office laptop?

Comment: good questions - I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're witnessing a bug where a password is required to unlock the settings, but the padlock is not shown.

I would suggest opening up `System Preferences > Security & Privacy` and unlock that using the padlock and your password. Then click on `Advanced` and ensure that `Require an administrator password to access system-wide preferences` is checked.

Now you should be able to go back to `Battery` settings, unlock the padlock and change the settings.